# Problem with changing python statement with python3 in macOS Catalina

Tags: python, macos, terminal, macos-catalina

By default when I type python in terminal it goes to python using the 2.7.x version. In oldest versions of macOS once I typed 'alias pyhton=python3' it changed forever and every time I typed python it goes to python version 3.
But in macOS Catalina, I need to type the statement every time I open the terminal.
Any suggestion?

Comment: add `alias python='python3'` to `.bashrc` in your home folder

Answer (score 2):

First up, confirm what your default "python" links to, so you can reference it, and ensure that which and the shell agree:

```
user:~> which python
/usr/bin/python
user:~> type python
python is /usr/bin/python
user:~> ls -la /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Oct  8 13:26 /usr/bin/python -> python2
```

Now you can either add an alias to override this in your shell... .

Open your ~/.bash_profile file for bash or ~/.zshrc file for zsh ([look here for historical reasons behind the files used](https://medium.com/@rajsek/zsh-bash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc-e30045652f2e)) as suggested by shahaf, and add a line with the alias — for example, quick method:

```
echo "alias python=/usr/bin/python3" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo "alias python=/usr/bin/python3" >> ~/.zshrc
```

The new alias will be set for the next shell you start, or, open a new Terminal window and source the profile file to make it active. Eg. in bash:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Or, change the symlink to point by default to python3, and remember the change (I use a simple toggle script, else any install of a missing python2 package can result in complaints about the configure script, which uses the python symlink directly):

```
#!/bin/bash
TOGGLE=$HOME/.python3Active
if [ ! -e $TOGGLE ]; then
        touch $TOGGLE
        sudo ln -fs python3 /usr/bin/python
        ls -la /usr/bin/python
        echo "Press any key to continue..."
        read
else
        rm $TOGGLE
        sudo ln -fs python2 /usr/bin/python
        ls -la /usr/bin/python
        echo "Press any key to continue..."
        read
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Catalina now uses `zsh` as the default rather than Bash.

To verify which shell you are using type `echo $0` in the terminal

Add `alias python='python3'` to $HOME/.zshrc

Answer (score 0):

you will have to edit the terminal's profile file, usually reside under `~/.profile`

add the alias line there, this files get loaded when a terminal session is started and export environment variables and methods so they will be accessible in that session

I suggest to use a more robust and powerful terminal enhancement like [Z-Shell](https://ohmyz.sh/)